# How to place dynamic error using Jquery validation using an array with field name and error message

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

In my project, I am getting the field validation error from PHP as an array. The structure is

```
$error_array = [
    'field_name1' => 'Error 1',
    'field_name2' => 'Error 2',
    'field_name3' => 'Error 3',
    'field_name4' => 'Error 4',
    'field_name5' => 'Error 5',        
];
echo json_encode($error_array);
```

**Is there any way to place these errors in the form using jquery validation library?** I tried, but didn't get any solution. **Right now I am identifying each field using jquery and placing the error using custom functions**. Searching for a simple solution for the same.

Comment: You tried?  Show us what you tried.  Why not `echo` the message into the JavaScript when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the array in your OP, the [JSON encoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) version would look like this...

```
{'field_name1':'Error 1','field_name2':'Error 2',...}
```

The structure of your JSON encoded array aligns perfectly with the acceptable structure of the `messages` object within `.validate()`...

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // your rules & options,
    messages: {
        'field_name1': 'Error 1',
        'field_name2': 'Error 2',
        ....
    }
});
```

So why can't you just `echo` the message into the JavaScript when the page is loaded...

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // your rules & options,
    messages: <?php echo json_encode($error_array); ?>
});
```

Please note that normally each message is assigned *to each rule* under each field `name`.  In your case, a single message is assigned to each field, so the same message will be used for *all rules* on one field.